# Problem downloading youtube video

Tags: ubuntu, download, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Youtube and Google video downloaders?](https://superuser.com/questions/6675/youtube-and-google-video-downloaders)

I am trying to download a video from YouTube using youtube-dl and get the below error. The error is only with only some videos. I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

```
youtube-dl -l http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3gu8kwD6lk

[youtube] Setting language

[youtube] K3gu8kwD6lk: Downloading video webpage

[youtube] K3gu8kwD6lk: Downloading video info webpage

[youtube] K3gu8kwD6lk: Extracting video information
ERROR: no fmt_url_map or conn information found in video info
```

Is there any solution/workaround for the above problem or are there any better alternatives?

Comment: [Bug report?](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues)

Comment: I am getting the same error. @Yitzchak, if that script is outdated, what will work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a GUI, I would recommend Video Download Helper; it is a rock solid Firefox extension that detects any flash media on a page (including YouTube) and gives you an easy menu to select it for download from.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/

Comment: That script is outdated and no longer works.

Comment: Was able to download it for most of the YouTube videos.

Comment: It is outdated for the html5 player. It should still work for videos on the old flash player.

Comment: try this one,  works like a charm  https://weibomiaopai.com/download-video-parser.php